# Scala java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type DenseVector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

My Scala code throws an error: `Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector [0.15935861532906645,0.15715807686945962, ... ]`

```
val joinedDf = sampleDf
  .join(
    normalizedParentEmbedding.select(col("parent_product"), col("normalized_vector").as("parent_vector")),
    Seq("parent_product"),
    "left"
  )
  .join(
    normalizedChildEmbeddingDf.select(col("child_product"), col("normalized_vector").alias("child_vector")),
    Seq("child_product"),
    "left"
  )
  .withColumn("parent_vector", when(col("parent_vector").isNull,
         lit(normalizedDefaultParentEmbeddingDf.select("parent_vector").head()(0))).otherwise(col("parent_vector")))  # ERROR!
  .withColumn("child_vector", when(col("child_vector").isNull,                
         lit(normalizedDefaultChildEmbeddingDf.select("child_vector").head()(0))).otherwise(col("child_vector")))
```

Even though I remove lit() I still get the same error.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you print the full error stack trace please? Also, which Spark version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Vector literals are not supported in spark. To overcome that limitation, you can use a UDF.

```scala
val parent_vect = normalizedDefaultParentEmbeddingDf.select("parent_vector").head()(0)
val child_vect = normalizedDefaultChildEmbeddingDf.select("child_vector").head()(0)

val parent_udf = udf(() => parent_vect)
val child_udf = udf(() => child_vect)

val joinedDf = [ ... ]
  .withColumn("parent_vector", when(col("parent_vector").isNull,
         parent_udf()).otherwise(col("parent_vector")))
  .withColumn("child_vector", when(col("child_vector").isNull,                
         child_udf()).otherwise(col("child_vector")))
```